# Reduce nested IF and sumifs in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I am trying to make excel formula based on drop down option with if and sumifs.

When drop down change it sum up vale on that basis. In current scenario formula is too long. Can someone help to optimise it. Below is example. Inputs like year and months etc is im drop down option.

```
=IF(C1=XX,IF(D1=YY,SUMIFS(),IF(D1=RR,SUMIFS(),IF(OR(),SUMIFS(),IF(C1=CC,IF(D1=YY,SUMIFS(),IF(D1=RR,SUMIFS(),IF(OR(),SUMIFS(),IF(C1=EE,IF(D1=YY,SUMIFS(),IF(D1=RR,SUMIFS(),IF(OR(),SUMIFS())
```

Comment: Please modify your question to explain the intended logic. It will probably be useful to have a view of the data (or a mockup of them) as well.

Comment: What’s your Excel version?

Comment: @Ricardo Diaz . Its excel 2016.

Comment: Got it, so IFs is not available. Please [edit] your question as suggested and post an image of what your data looks like and describe what you intend to achieve

Answer (score 0):

If you have a quite recent version of excel there is the IFS functions, so your code would become like this:

```
=IF(C1=XX,IFS(D1=YY,SUMIFS(),D1=RR,SUMIFS(),OR(),SUMIFS(),C1=CC,D1=YY,SUMIFS(),D1=RR,SUMIFS(),OR(),SUMIFS(),C1=EE,D1=YY,SUMIFS(),D1=RR,SUMIFS(),OR(),SUMIFS()),ELSE)
```

Please note that to me your code lacks of the else clause for the first IF and a lot of closing brackets; indeed if I have understood corretly your intentions, the code shoudl first verify whether C1=XX; if so, it should verify several conditions and do something according to the verified condition, but you did not specify what it should do if C1 is not equal to XX

Comment: Nice idea let me check. But my intention is to make.it small some way.

Comment: With formulas I don't know any other method. Looks like there are tons of conditions to check, so no way out